# If TouchLocation is NOT Within Bounds

Tags: swift, if-statement, sprite-kit, contains

For the below code, I need to see whether the touchLoaction is not within the bounds of a button, but the problem I have is a can't use !=, so I'm not 100% sure of what I need to enter instead. Every time I search the web for "if not equal", it only brings up the "!=" example, which doesn't work in this instance.

```
let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

if button.containsPoint(touchLocation) { // NEEDS TO BE NOT CONTAINSPOINT OR SOMETHING

   print("not on button")

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `if (button.containsPoint(touchLocation) == False)`

> **Declaration**
>
> *Swift*: `func containsPoint(_ point: CGPoint) -> Bool`
>
> *Objective-C*: `- (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)point`

In both languages `containsPoint` returns a BOOL (which can be equal to false.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I knew there would be a simple answer to this problem, I just couldn't find it. I'll make the answer as correct once it lets me (7 minutes time).

Comment: @Jarron If this answers did help you, consider it to mark as 'answer'. It might help others.

Comment: Yep will do, it's says I have to wait though.

Comment: Or simply `if !button.containsPoint(touchLocation) { ... }`